# Can we use Kunen's inconsistency theorem in NFU+AC?

Tags: set-theory

> I [know](https://mathoverflow.net/a/136067/143814) we can't formalize the Kunen inconsistency as an assertion in the first-order language of set theory. But
>   [the wikipedia say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#Strong_axioms_of_infinity) "**Con([MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory) + The proper class ordinal is a measurable cardinal.)**$\leftrightarrow$ **Con([NFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) + Infinity + Large Ordinals + Small Ordinals)**", So I think it's no problem for **NFU**.

**NFU** is a non-well founded set theory. NFU had Universal set **V**, Universal set cardinal and automorphism j, NFU's axiom schema of comprehension is very different from **[MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory)/[TG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory)**, They are very important in Kunen's inconsistency theorem. So a interesting question is:

Can we use Kunen's inconsistency theorem in **NFU + AC**, to proof **NFU + AC + Reinhardt/super Reinhardt/totally Reinhardt/limit club Berkeley cardinal** $\to 0=1$?

Comment: This question would be better with 1) a link to the Wikipedia article, 2) a more standard choice of which paragraphs to highlight, 3) a clearer statement of why this inconsistency can’t be formalized in the usual way, and 4) a main question whose first presentation is not distracted with slashes, and which leaves the alternative questions for a separate paragraph.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you, link add finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, NFU + AC is going to have exactly the same possible large cardinals as ordinary set theory.  NFU + AC has the same stratified mathematics as ordinary set theory.  There will be no interesting results of this kind, unless they involve unstratified assertions in the language of NFU.

I should be slightly more explicit.  NFU + AC has the same strength as bounded Zermelo set theory.  However, there will be models of NFU + AC associated with any of the usual levels of strength we are used to.